# Is it Possible to run both Server and Client android applications Locally?

Tags: java, android, network-programming

I'm looking to program a network application. I was going through: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee368/Android/Tutorial-3-Server-Client-Communication-for-Android.pdf which talk about server and client programming for android. Now imagine I don't have an internet connection and I want both server and client applications run on either same android device or different android devices locally.

Is it possible to develop and run both server and client applications using TCPIP/UDP/Multicast locally on either standalone android device or multiple android device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to communicate between Android devices or applications that are not connected to the Internet.

If you are using different devices, you probably want to use sockets, but it is possible to run an HTTP server on the server device and then use HTTP. Make sure they are connected to the same wifi network.

There are several different ways to communicate between different processes on the same Android device. The easiest might be to use a [Messenger service](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger) but sockets and HTTP are also possible here.

Comment: HTTP is what I'm looking at, but what if a wifi network isn't available? I'm looking at can both a server application and client application run simultaneously in android?

Comment: Yes. Obviously if no network is available then they have to be on the same device.

Comment: But how can two app run independently on android? See I've server and client application which uses TCPIP/UDP/Multicast, how can I create a local network just like when you develop on windows, you use localhost or 192 series http.

Comment: Yes, two applications can run independently on android. Normally Android kills background applications unpredictably, so you probably want the server to be a foreground service (Google it). You can access localhost just like on any other system.

Comment: Can a server send data as a TCPIP/UDP/multicast service to other applications on android?

Comment: Could you share any example what you just said?

Comment: If its local, then what will be the PORT nos, IP ADDR or GROUP ADDR?

Comment: Same as they would be on any non-android system. Port number is whatever you want. IP address is 127.0.0.1. I don't know what a group address is.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it is possible in some manner.You can either use sqlite database present in android device to store various types of data in table form and data retreive from same.

Another way is to use [Parse](https://www.parse.com/) cloud as a server or backend of your client application.It allows your app to run even when you are not connected to internet.It stores the data in cache memory with its api and then uploads data to the server cloud as soon as you get connected to Intenet.

You can ask if you have any further queries. :)

Comment: See what I"m looking at two independant apps on android to interact locally without any internet connection. For example, if you see when you develop server & client applicaiton on windows, you test it with http://localhost or http://192.168.1.10 or similar things. Doesn't Android have some features like this?

Comment: you can go for sqlite database using content provide that is some sort of central repository. if you want do something like that.Android doesn't feature as in windows where we can test on local host

Comment: I think Android might have an option, please follow the other answer thread:http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986212/3176433